# Kitted / Bundled Items in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am wanting to create kitted items in my magento store.. the reasoning behind this is because we sell kitted items which are our individual products that are created as CUSTOM KITS WITH DIFFERENT PRICING.. the only problem is I cannot seem to display the options that come with the products? So I want to have my kits (bundled product) display other individual products <-- but also be able to pick the attributes related with these items.. size/height color etc… Is this possible?